# Проверка есть параметр или нет

Tags: discord.py, view, nextcord

Вот есть обычное модельное окно.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Your pet")  # Modal title

        # Create a text input and add it to the modal
        self.name = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label="Your pet's name",
            min_length=2,
            max_length=50,
        )
        self.add_item(self.name)

        # Create a long text input and add it to the modal
        self.description = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label="Description",
            style=nextcord.TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            placeholder="Information that can help us recognise your pet",
            required=False,
            max_length=1800,
        )
        self.add_item(self.description)

    async def callback(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction) -> None:
        """This is the function that gets called when the submit button is pressed"""
        response = f"{interaction.user.mention}'s favourite pet's name is {self.name.value}."
        if self.description.value != "":
            response += f"\nTheir pet can be recognized by this information:\n{self.description.value}"
        await interaction.send(response)

@bot.slash_command(
    name="pet",
    description="Describe your favourite pet",
    guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID],
)
async def send(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    # sending the modal on an interaction (can be slash, buttons, or select menus)
    modal = Pet()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
```

как мне проверить введен ли параметр self.name ? Типа такова.

```
if self.name.value == 0:
   self.name.value = {interaction.user.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяй длину

```
if len(self.name.value) == 0:
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no Attrebute 'value'

Comment: а я тут при чем? Значит, и раньше эта ошибка была.

Comment: Ты гений? Value - это в твоей строке каторую ты дал...

Comment: А ты альтернативно одаренный? Посмотри в собственный код в вопросе после слов "типа такова".